# Oidc redirect to signin-callback.html

Tags: reactjs, openid-connect, oidc-client-js, react-oidc

I'm stuck on this for the past few days. I'm having an issue authenticating with Oidc, I'm trying to redirect to a `signin-callback.html` after authentication but I'm unable to call an HTML page directly from my react app, during my research I've seen examples of this using typescript, but I'm not sure why it's not working in my JS web app.

from my research online it seems that i need to redirect to the `signin-callback.html` in order to get my auth token but that's where im stuck

any help would be appreciated

signin-callback.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Authentification callback processing..</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>

    <h1>Authentification callback processing...</h1>

    <script src="oidc-client.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Oidc.UserManager({ response_mode: "query" }).signinRedirectCallback().then(function () {
            console.log("Ter")
            window.location = "index.html";
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

settings

```
const settings = {
    authority: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHORITY}`,
    client_id: `${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID}`,
    redirect_uri: `${process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI}`,
    response_type: `${process.env.REACT_APP_RESPONSE_TYPE}`,
    metadataUrl: `${process.env.REACT_APP_METADATA_URL}`,

};
```

main.js

```
const getUserInfo = async () => {
    userManager.getUser().then(async (user) => {
        if (user) {
            console.log('User has been successfully loaded from store.');
            // console.log(username)
            dispatch({ type: "JWT", payload: { displayName: username.data.DisplayName, user: user } });
        } else {
            console.log('You are not logged in.');
            userManager.signinRedirect();
        }
    });
}
useEffect(() => {
    // Test()
    getUserInfo()
}, [])
```

Comment: Are you sure this code needs to run in another html file? Can it not be included with your React app code?

Comment: I tried, but it the callback won't work for some reason unless it's in an html page.

Comment: I'm actually close to figuring out, it looks like if I import the html page via the web config it does seem to be working once I have a solid answer I'll post it

Answer (score 1):

While I am sure you have moved on, this worked for me using react-oidc-context plugin. A simple direct function for the onSigninCallback property will resolve your issue. See screenshot below.

`const oidcConfig = {
    authority: "https://localhost:44310/",
    client_id: "react_public_web_client",
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
    response_type: "code",
    scope: "openid email profile roles my_backend_api",
};

function onSigninCallback() {
    window.location.href = "/";
}

root. Render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AuthProvider {...oidcConfig} onSigninCallback={onSigninCallback}>
          <App />
        </AuthProvider>
      </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);`

Comment: Please provide the code example as code, not as a screenshot. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In an SPA you should be able to just set the redirect to the SPA's main URL. Then, whenever the page loads, look for an OIDC login response, via the `code`, `error` and `state` parameters.If found, then call `userManager.signInRedirectCallback()`. I used to use this library a lot, and here are some examples:

- [Configuration](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/spa.config.json)
- [Page Load](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/app/app.ts#L46)
- [Calls to signInRedirect and signInRedirectCallback](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L107)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/28/basicspa-codingkeypoints/)

Here is a [React based example](https://github.com/curityio/spa-using-token-handler/blob/main/spa/src/views/pageLoad/pageLoadView.tsx), to handle page loads and check for an OAuth response. Note that this does not use the oidc-client library and instead uses a more up to date `Back End for Front End`  approach.

Answer (score 0):

After doing lots more research i was able to include the html page in via the webconfig file and redirect to it without a component

My webconfig

```
  plugins: [
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'public/assets/favicon.ico', to: 'assets/favicon.ico' },
        { from: 'public/assets/manifest.json', to: 'assets/manifest.json' },
        { from: './public/signin-callback.html', to: 'signin-callback.html' },
        { from: 'public/silent-renew.html', to: 'silent-renew.html' },
        { from: './public/oidc-client.min.js', to: 'oidc-client.min.js' },
      ],
    }),
  ],
```